# Pyglet - Could not create UTF8 text property

Tags: python, arcade

I am trying to follow a guide about game developing using python and the 'acrade' package.
I have installed arcade using: (I'm using linux)

```
pip3 install arcade
```

Then I have tried to compile the following code to test the freshly installed package:

```
import arcade

SCREEN_WIDTH = 600
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

arcade.open_window(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "Drawing Example")

arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.WHITE)

arcade.start_render()

x = 300
y = 300
radius = 200
arcade.draw_circle_filled(x, y, radius, arcade.color.YELLOW)

x = 370
y = 350
radius = 20
arcade.draw_circle_filled(x, y, radius, arcade.color.BLACK)

x = 230
y = 350
radius = 20
arcade.draw_circle_filled(x, y, radius, arcade.color.BLACK)

x = 300
y = 280
width = 120
height = 100
start_angle = 190
end_angle = 350
arcade.draw_arc_outline(x, y, width, height, arcade.color.BLACK, start_angle, end_angle, 10)

arcade.finish_render()

arcade.run()
```

I get the following errors:

```
  File "/home/beewulf/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 805, in _set_text_property
    raise XlibException('Could not create UTF8 text property')
pyglet.window.xlib.XlibException: Could not create UTF8 text property
```

I have tried following the solution in [https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/673]
But it didn't work.

Anyone has any idea?